# Spring MVC:ERROR 404-Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm a beginner in Spring framework. I'm trying to build a shopping project in Spring MVC framework. The project is to implement a shopping cart (but in small scale). It includes 2 JSP files as a view to take users requests and respond to them, namely `ViewAddproduct.jsp` and `ViewCart.asp`. In addition, the project has 4 files `pom.xml`, `web.xml`, `NikiAbb-servlet.xml` and `AddController.java`. (I open Maven project and add all required dependencies) It seems all code or added dependencies in my files are correct and I can run each page individually on the server (Tomcat). But when I run whole package I get error 404. I have checked lots of tutorials to solve it but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using JDK 9.0.4, Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Oxygen 2 Release (4.7.2), and Tomcat 9

Package hierarchy:

[image]

pom.xml

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>NikiAbb</groupId>
    <artifactId>Testut</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <name>Testut Maven Webapp</name>
     <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
     <java.version>9.0.4</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
      <finalName>Testut</finalName>
    </build>
 </project>
```

web.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
   "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
     <web-app >

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
       <servlet>
   <servlet-name>NikiAbb</servlet-name>

   <servlet-   
     class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NikiAbb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

NikiAbb-servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
  <context:component-scan base-package = "NikiCart" />

  <bean class    
 = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
     <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>

   </beans>
```

Addcontroller.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller

public class AddController
{

   @RequestMapping("/add")
   public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletRespose   
   response)
   {
    int H-box=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("horse-box");
    int H-unit=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("horse-unit");
    int P-box=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ping-box");
    int P-unit=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ping-unit");




    AddService as = new AddService();

    if (H-box=!"") || (H-uint=!)
    {
        int k = as.add(H-box,H-uint,0);
    }else if(P-box=!"") || (P-uint=!)
    { 
    int k = as.add(P-box,P-uint,1);

    }

    ModelAddview mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("ViewCart.jsp");
    mv.addObject("Apro-price",k);


    return mv;
    }
    }
```

ViewAddproduct.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01     
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 </head>
 <body>

  <h1 align="center">Wellcome To Online Shopping</h1>
  <h3 align="center"><font color="blue">Get 10% Discount for shopping 3 box 
  or more</font></h3>
  </br></br>
  <form action ="add">
     <table border="1" align="center">

        <tr>
          <td align="center"><img 
    src="http://www.yourpresents.co.uk/user/products/large/penguine-figurine-        trinket-box.jpg" alt="penguin" height="420" width="400"/> 
           </br></br>
           <font size=5>Penguin-jewelry-box</font></br>
           <font size=3>Price per box : 175 Nok</br>
           20 Unit in each box</font>

           </br></br><font size=3>Number Of Box : </font><input name="ping-          box" type="number" min="0" max="50" step="1" value ="0"/>

           </br></br><font size=3>Number Of Units : </font><input name="ping-          unit" type="number" min="0" max="50" step="1" value ="0"/>

           </br>

           </br>
           <input type = "button" value = "Add To Cart"/>
           </br>
           </td>
          <td align="center" height="420" width="400"><img 
      src="https://cdn0.rubylane.com/shops/632271/005849.1L.jpg" alt="horse"
    height="320" width="300"> 
          </br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
          <font size=5>HorseShoe-Card</font>
          </br>
          <font size=3>Price per box : 829 Nok</font></br>
           5 Units in each box</font>

           </br></br><form:label path = "horse-box"><font size=3>Number Of   
          Box : </font></form:label><form:input path="horse-box"  


           </br></br><form:label path = "horse-unit"><font size=3>
           Number Of Units : </font></form:label><form:input 
      path="horse- unit" type="number" min="0" max="50" step="1" value ="0"/>


          </br></br>
          <input type = "button" value = "Add To Cart"/>
          </br>
          </td>

        </tr>

     </table>  

      </form>
     </body>
   </html>
```

ViewCart.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

     </head>
    <hr width="1700" size="2" color="black">
     <table border="0.5" align="left">

        <tr align="center"><td width="400">
           <img   
    src="http://www.yourpresents.co.uk/user/products/large/penguine-figurine-         trinket-box.jpg" alt="penguin" height="220" width="200"/> </td>
           <td width="300">
           <font size=5 color="blue">${product-name}</font></td>
           <td width="700" align="right"><font size=3>Amount:</font></br>
                  <font size=3>${Aprod-box}</font><font size=3>Box</font>
                      </br>
                     <font size=3>${Aprod-unit}Units</font>
     </br></br></br></br></br><font size=3></font>Price:
                     <font size=4>${Apro-price}</font>
                                        </td>

        </tr>
        <tr><td width="700">

      <hr width="1700" size="1" color="black"></td>></tr>


        <tr align="cente" ><td width="700" align="left">
           <font size=4>Total:</font>

        <td width="400" align="right"><font size=5>${price-total}  Nok</font>
                   </td>
          </tr>

     <tr> <td>
  </br></br></br>
  <font align="center"></font></font><input type = "submit"
   style="height:50px;width:250px" value = "continoue to shopping"/>
     <input type = "submit" align="center" style="height:50px;width:250px"
      value = "continue shopping"/>
      </td></tr></table>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: How did you resolve it? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

@ NikiAbb-servlet.xml file `<property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />` should be `<property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/" />` couldn't see any jsp folder under WEB-INF.

@ Addcontroller.java
`@RequestMapping("/add")
   public ModelAndView.add(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletRespose rsponse)` should remove that "." `@RequestMapping("/addProd")
   public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest`. Even your RequestMapping also wrong.

Another thing `mv.setViewName("ViewCart.jsp");`, no need to add .jsp again just change as `mv.setViewName("ViewCart");`.

Comment: yes you are right. I don't understand what do you mean "Even your RequestMapping also wrong". I apply all modifications but i got "ERROR 404-Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Comment: I am wondering about one thing, when I run my project from Localhost:8080/Test/ViewAddprod.jsp , the page pop up but when I click on "Add to cart" button nothing happens. it seems servlet can connect files together or ...

Comment: I meant already your was this `@RequestMapping("/add")` but your form target was 'addProd'. So it could never called your add method in Controller class. If target is 'addProd' then `@RequestMapping(''/addProd")`. [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkIkQD0GKgk) this is a basic tutorial.

Comment: yes. I have already corrected it. but the problem still remains.ERROR 404-Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Comment: Move your ViewAddprod.jsp & ViewCart.jsp into WEB-INF folder

Comment: I did that but error still remains. I got this warning in console window :WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Testut/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'NikiAbb'

Comment: @NikNik it's a issue about your jsp file path...if you correct it properly, you could able to see results.

Comment: could you please explaine more. what do you mean "correct Jsp file path"?in controller?

Comment: As on this `<property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />` your jsp files should be in jsp sub-folder under WEB-INF Folder. Parent is WEB-INF and Child Folder is jsp. your jsp file must me inside of jsp folder.